# Laravel Passport and mobile apps

Tags: laravel, rest, api, laravel-passport

I need create REST API for android and ios apps. It will be small social network. Which way is better to use? Client Grant Tokens or Personal Access Tokens. Help me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Laravel Sanctum` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum

Laravel Sanctum provides a featherweight authentication system for SPAs (single page applications), mobile applications, and simple, token based APIs. Sanctum allows each user of your application to generate multiple API tokens for their account. These tokens may be granted abilities / scopes which specify which actions the tokens are allowed to perform.

Comment: Can I get posts, messages uses sanctum or only for auth?

Comment: @rus131354 what do you mean by posts and messages?

Comment: any data from db

Comment: @rus131354 both passport and Sanctum  are for authentication and authorization, it's all about permissions, there is nothing to do querying data from db. you can do whatever you want once you have the access. The thing is that they are all for protecting your system.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Passport is also useful.
Laravel already makes it easy to perform authentication via traditional login forms, but what about APIs? APIs typically use tokens to authenticate users and do not maintain session state between requests. Laravel makes API authentication a breeze using Laravel Passport, which provides a full OAuth2 server implementation for your Laravel application in a matter of minutes. 
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport